# Clearner way to wait for function to complete before continuing

Tags: javascript, async-await

First I fetch a random quote from a public api. Only AFTER I actually have a quote I want to render the page including that quote.

I am a JavaScript newbie so please bear with me if this is a stupid question.

I was struggling with waiting for the api call to return BEFORE continuing with rendering the page.
I wanted to do the following, but this doesn't work because `res.render` will be called before I have a quote. (note: I am using Express and Axios)

```
async function getRandomQuote() {
    try {
        const res = await axios.get("https://api.quotable.io/random?tags=famous-quotes")
        console.log(`${res.data.content} - ${res.data.author}`)     //This prints fine
        return res.data
    } catch(e) {
        console.log('error', e)
    }
}

app.get('/', (req, res) => {

    const quote = getRandomQuote()
    console.log(`${quote.content} - ${quote.author}`)    //This prints 'undefined' because 'getRandomQuote' isn't finished yet

    res.render('home', { quote })
})
```

The only way I figured out to do it is as follows, but I find this really messy.
Is there a cleaner way to do this? Or do I always need to put all the lines of code that I want to wait for each other in an async function?

```
async function getRandomQuote() {
    try {
        const res = await axios.get("https://api.quotable.io/random?tags=famous-quotes")
        console.log(`${res.data.content} - ${res.data.author}`)     //This prints fine
        return res.data
    } catch(e) {
        console.log('error', e)
    }
}

app.get('/', (req, res) => {

    const getQuoteAndRender = async() => {
        const quote = await getRandomQuote()
        console.log(`${quote.content} - ${quote.author}`)    //This prints only if I wrap everything in yet another aync function, otherwise it will not wait for 'getRandomQuote' to complete

        res.render('home', { quote })
    }
    getQuoteAndRender()
})
```

(Note: I realize rendering the page after I successfully get a quote is not ideal either because this means I will not get a page at all if the quote api (for some reason) doesn't work. But for now I just want to know how to do this with the waiting.)

Comment: put the `async` before `(req, res) => {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres what you need to do. Make your controller `async` by doing this `app.get('/', async (req, res)`

```
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {

const quote = await getRandomQuote()
console.log(`${quote.content} - ${quote.author}`)    //This prints 'undefined' because 'getRandomQuote' isn't finished yet

res.render('home', { quote })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
getRandomQuote()
.then(quote => {
  console.log(`${quote.content} - ${quote.author}`) 
  res.render('home', { quote })
});
```

Comment: That works! So .then also automatically waits.

Comment: Yes, it is a part of the [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) API and works if you return a `Promise` in your function or if you declared the function with `async`.